# People.aspx reverts the master page with query string parameters

Tags: 2013, master-page, system-master-page

I have a custom System Master Page. When I am on the People and Groups page `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=5`, my master page looks fine. However, when I change the View *or* go to the next page if the group has more than 30 members, the master page changes back to the default!

The URL gets a few more query string parameters that seem to cause the master page to be reverted (not just a post back), as fresh requests still cause the master page to revert with either the `View` query string parameter or the `p_Title` query string parameter. Obviously I *don't* want the master page to change, but my body tag is definitely being replaced so I don't think this is a delegate problem.

Comment: Once the master page change to default and if you try to open any system page does the master page get reset to custom?

Comment: The default master is only set while viewing that page. Navigating away to other pages still use our custom master page.